# Less-than operator causes error "not well-formed" in xsl-if

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm going through the w3cschools XSLT tutorial, and I am at this page: [xsl-if](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_if.asp).
On that page (in red) is the text `<xsl:if test="price &gt; 10">`. This works. I modified the code to use `"&lt;"` and that works fine too. 

I tested `<xsl:if test="price > 10">` (note the use of `>` instead of the `&gt;`). This works too.
**But this fails:** `<xsl:if test="price < 10">`. Error is `XML Parsing Error: not well-formed`  and it points to the `<` symbol in the expression.
If the `>` symbol worked fine, why did using the `<` fail? (I'm using FireFox)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> If the > symbol worked fine, why did
>   using the < fail? (I'm using FireFox)

Because the "<" character is one of the few that are illegal within an attribute value (it is the start-of tag character).

From the **[XML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-common-syn)**

```
[10]    AttValue    ::=    '"' ([^<&"] | Reference)* '"'
```

As can be clearly seen, the "<" and "&" characters are not allowed in any attribute value.

**Update**: As noticed by @Tomalak, the above should read:

As can be clearly seen, the "<" and "&" characters (unless the latter is part of an entity reference or character reference) are not allowed in any attribute value.

Comment: +1 - Though the last comment is a bit misleading: The `&` is not allowed *unless* it is part of an XML entity.

Comment: @Tomalak: `&` character is not allowed in attribute value. There is no `&` character in an entity reference, because an entity reference is an entity by itself. And so is treated in attribute normalization face (by XML parser or some API)

Comment: @Alejandro: Not sure if I understand your objection. `&amp;` is an entity reference, it contains an `&` character, and it is allowed in an attribute value. Maybe I was a bit sloppy in my use of "entity" when I meant "entity reference".

Comment: @Tomalak: `&amp;` is an entity reference with character `&` as **replacement text**. So, with this document `<elem attr="&gt;"/>`, this function call `contains(/elem/@attr,'&amp;')` allways evaluate to false.

Comment: got this instantly from the error message, but how do I do the less-than operator then...? :( should `<xsl:if test="price &lt; 10">` actually work?! - ah it does, my wrong. I mistyped node for name at one place.

Comment: @naxa, yes, and if you want to avoid escaping completely, use: `not(price >= 10)`

Answer (score 6):

You can also see the answer to this on w3schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_syntax.asp

> Entity References
>
> Some characters have a special meaning
>   in XML.
>
> If you place a character like "<"
>   inside an XML element, it will
>   generate an error **because the parser
>   interprets it as the start of a new
>   element**.

Answer (score 4):

The unencoded "opening" bracket `<` is generally invalid in XML attribute values [as per the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#CleanAttrVals).

While the "closing" bracket `>` is allowed, using it is actually bad style (IMHO). XML attribute values have to be XML-encoded, period.

Comment: @Tomalak: Why, using '>" instead of `'&gt;'` makes the code so more readable. I even usually reverse  `x &lt; y` to `not(x > y -1)`

Comment: @Dimitre: That's why I wrote "IMHO". I am quite strict when it comes to value encoding, and I consciously avoid shortcuts and loopholes even if they are documented. `x &lt; y` disturbs my flow of reading not at all. However, seeing `not(x > y -1)` would make me stop and think - even if just for a second. Why should I want that? For me, the increased readability does not outweigh the time I need to think about the expression. For me, it's not economic.

Comment: I think that the reverse of `x &lt; y` it should be `y > x`. And is more readable and more economic. Plus, I never understand why `<` could break the parser and `>` don't! Ja!

Comment: @Alexandro: No, the reverse of `x &lt; y` is `y >= x` :)

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: No, you're wrong. Let `x` and `y` both be 2. `2 &lt; 2` is false. But `2 >= 2` is true, so the expressions are not equivalent. @Alejandro is correct.

Comment: @Eric: By "reverse" I mean the logical negation: `not(x &lt; y)` is equivalent to `y >= x`

Comment: :)  So it looks like Tomalek was right in the first place  ;)